# Extracting tfidf-vectors by key without destroying the fileformat

Tags: apache-pig, extract, mahout

I have about 200000 tfidf-vectors in the output-format seq2sparse delivers. Now I need to extract 500 but not randomly like with the split-function. I know the keys of 500 of them and I need them in the same dataformat like the one from seq2sparse.
When I open the sequencefile with the 200000 entries I can see that the keys are coded with
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text and the values with org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable.

But when I try to use
https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/mahout/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/mahout/VectorWritableConverter.java

and

https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/pig/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/store/SequenceFileStorage.java

in Pig Latin for reading and writing them the output has org.apache.hadoop.io.Text for both key and value.

I really need exactly those 500 entries in this format because I want to use them in trainnb and testnb.

---

Basically it would be enough to know how I can do something like the reverse of mahout seqdumper.

Answer (score 0):

While there's no specific Mahout command to do this you could write a relatively simple utility function Using Mahout's:

```
org.apache.mahout.common.Pair;
org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.sequencefile.SequenceFileIterable;
org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;
```

and:

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
com.google.common.io.Closeables;
```

You could do something like the following:

```
// load up the 500 desired keys with some function
Vector<Text>desiredKeys = getDesiredKeys();
//create a new SequenceFile writer for the 500 Desired Vectors 
SequenceFile.Writer writer =
        SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf, output500filePath ,
                                  Text.class,
                                  VectorWritable.class);         
try {
  // create an iterator over the tfidfVector sequence file 
  SequenceFileIterable<Text, VectorWritable>seqFileIterable =
          new SequenceFileIterable<Text, VectorWritable>(
              tfidfVectorPath, true, conf)

  // loop over tfidf sequence file and write out only Pairs with keys
  // contained in the desiredKeys Vector to the output500file 
  for (Pair<Text, VectorWritable> pair : seqFileIterable) {
      if(desiredKeys.contains(pair.getFirst())){
            writer.append(pair.getFirst(),pair.getSecond());
      }
  }
}finally {
  Closeables.close(writer, false);
}
```

And use the path to the "output500file" for the input to trainnb.  Using vector.contains() is not the the most efficient way to do it, but this would be the general idea.